# How can I change the properties which appear in the SSMS Filter Settings?

Tags: ssms

How can I change the properties which appear in the SSMS Filter Settings? For example: how can I remove 'Durability Type' and add 'Filegroup'?

[image: Filter Settings]

Comment: SSMS does not include this functionality, but non-free Add-ins might exist that extend this functionality...